# Making calls to Google service account without using domain admin user

Tags: java, google-api, google-directory-api

I am attempting to use the Directory API to update Google passwords for users in our domain. I've followed the example for the Plus service account, which is almost identical (https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client-samples/blob/master/plus-serviceaccount-cmdline-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/plus/serviceaccount/cmdline/PlusServiceAccountSample.java).

I'm trying to determine why I am required to pass in the email address of a super admin user to the setServiceAccountUser() in order to set user passwords on the domain.  Is there a setting somewhere that will let me use the API without settings the serviceAccountUser?

I receive the message below when I comment out the setServiceAccountUser() call:

```
{
"code" : 403,
"errors" : [ {
"domain" : "global",
"message" : "Not Authorized to access this resource/api",
"reason" : "forbidden"
} ],
"message" : "Not Authorized to access this resource/api"
```

Here is the code (from the Plus sample) that is relevant:

```
// service account credential (uncomment setServiceAccountUser for domain-wide delegation)
    GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(httpTransport)
        .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
        .setServiceAccountId(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL)
        .setServiceAccountScopes(Collections.singleton(PlusScopes.PLUS_ME))
        .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File("key.p12"))
        // .setServiceAccountUser("user@example.com")
        .build();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directory API write operations require an admin account. Either a super admin or a [delegated admin](https://support.google.com/a/answer/33325?hl=en) who has rights to perform API user modifications. This is listed in the [prerequisites](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/prerequisites) document.

Comment: Thanks... I didn't quite understand why this is the case b/c you don't have to pass the admin user's credentials along with the call meaning you could essentially pass in any admin user's email address to this property just by knowing the email address.  Maybe Google added this as a requirement to prevent an accidental write call from being made?